Typescript error TP1001 when creating a Web Worker in Next.js 15.0.2 with Stockfish chess engine
I'm working on a Next.js 15.0.2 project with turbopack using TypeScript, and I'm integrating the Stockfish chess engine to create a Web Worker on the client side.
The Stockfish library is stored in the public folder, and the client fetches it and creates the Worker with the following code:
const stockfishPath = '/stockfish/stockfish-nnue-16-single.js';

const createStockfishWorker = () => {
  try {
    const worker = new Worker(stockfishPath);
    return worker;
  } catch (error) {
    throw Error(`Initialize stockfish worker failed: ${error}`);
  }
};

export default createStockfishWorker;

The Stockfish library loads and works perfectly in the client. However, when I run the project, I get the following TypeScript error in the console:
GET /analysis/w 200 in 2089ms
⚠ ./src/services/stockfish/createStockfishWorker.ts:7:20
error TP1001 new Worker("/stockfish/stockfish-nnue-16-single.js") is not statically analysable
   5 | const createStockfishWorker = () => {
   6 |   try {
>  7 |     const worker = new Worker(stockfishPath);
     |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   8 |     postMessage(['uci'], worker);
   9 |     return worker;
  10 |   } catch (error) {

What I tried:

The Web Worker is being created dynamically, and it works fine, so I don't see any issues with the functionality.
The error message TP1001 seems to be TypeScript complaining that new Worker("/stockfish/stockfish-nnue-16-single.js") is not statically analysable.
I have tried to use // @ts-ignore to suppress the error, but it doesn't seem to resolve it.

My setup:

Next.js version: 15.0.2
TypeScript version: ^5
Stockfish library is being served from the public folder

What I need help with:

Why is TypeScript showing this error if the worker is working fine?
How can I resolve or suppress this error effectively?
Is there a better way to load workers dynamically in Next.js with TypeScript that avoids this error?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
